# How to find function satisfying a known sum over it?

Tags: calculus

I've got the following (simplified somewhat) situation;

$f(x) = A(e^{-x/B} - e^{-x/C}) = \sum\limits_{n=x}^{x+f(x - 1)D} p(n)$

Is there a way to find $p(n)$?

Math is not my specialization and regrettably I can't find much usable examples.